# Electric Range Element Replacement

Tags: wiring, stove, range

[image]I've got an old Philco electric range that needs a couple of 6" elements replaced but parts are near impossible to find.

The Philco elements have 3 wires while modern elements only use 2 wires.

Is it possible to hook up a modern element to my old Philco stove?

[image]

Comment: if you could post photos of the elements we may be able to provide better advice. The model of the range would also be helpful. right now we don't know it it may be a ground wire or a dual heat element.

Answer (score 1):

Without being able to test and troubleshoot your coils it is difficult to say but it appears your coils are two 120 volt coils with a center common to both coils. The white wire marked "Com".

You would need to take a voltage reading on the two outside terminals of the coils to see if you get 240 volts.

If that is the case, then a two wire heating element would connect to the two outside wires and the center wire would just get capped off.

Range heating elements are normally rated for 240 volts.

Good luck!